# Question about GPU performance (RTX 3060 6Gb Laptop VS Tesla T4)

Tags: c++, cuda

I recently started studying C++ and CUDA programing and I am porting a function to CUDA. So, I have some questions about the performance in two different systems. The C++ version is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "cmath"

void wavevector(int rx, int ry, int rz, 
                double *wavevectorX, double *wavevectorY, 
                double *wavevectorZ, double boxLength[3]){
    int igx, igy, igz;
    int lgx, lgy, lgz;
    int igk;

    double waveX, waveY, waveZ; 

    for(igz = 0; igz < rz; igz++){
        lgz = ((igz + (rz / 2 - 1)) % rz) - (rz / 2 - 1);

        for(igy = 0; igy < ry; igy++){
            lgy = ((igy + (ry / 2 - 1)) % ry) - (ry / 2 - 1);

            for(igx= 0; igx < rx/2; igx++){
                lgx = ((igx + (rx / 2 - 1)) % rx) - (rx / 2 - 1);
                

                igk = 1 + igx + igy * rx / 2 + igz * ry * rx / 2;
                
                waveX = 2 * M_PI / boxLength[0] * lgx;
                waveY = 2 * M_PI / boxLength[1] * lgy;
                waveZ = 2 * M_PI / boxLength[2] * lgz;
                
                wavevectorX[igk] = waveX;
                wavevectorY[igk] = waveY;
                wavevectorZ[igk] = waveZ;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "======================== Start! ========================" << std::endl;
    int rx = 500, ry = 500, rz = 500;
    int N = rx * ry * rz / 2 + 1;
    double *wavevectorX;
    double *wavevectorY;
    double *wavevectorZ;

    double boxLength[3];
    boxLength[0] = 3;
    boxLength[1] = 3;
    boxLength[2] = 3;

    // Allocate Unified Memory -- accessible from CPU or GPU
    wavevectorX = new double[N+1];
    wavevectorY = new double[N+1];
    wavevectorZ = new double[N+1];

    wavevector(rx, ry, rz, 
               wavevectorX, wavevectorY, wavevectorZ, 
               boxLength);

    std::cout << "========================= End! =========================" << std::endl;

    int start_p = 1;
    int end_p = 20;
    for(int i = start_p; i < end_p; i++){
        std::cout << "wavevectorX[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorX[i] << 
        " || wavevectorY[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorY[i] << 
        " || wavevectorZ[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorZ[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Free memory
    delete [] wavevectorX;
    delete [] wavevectorY;
    delete [] wavevectorZ;

    return 0;
}
```

I have ported it to CUDA as (**Edit:** as suggested in the comments below, I am using single precision to get a better performance from CUDA):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "cmath"

// CUDA kernel to calculate wavevectors
__global__ void wavevector(int n, int rx, int ry, int rz, 
                           float *wavevectorX, float *wavevectorY, 
                           float *wavevectorZ, float bLx, float bLy, 
                           float bLz){
    int lgz, lgy, lgx, igk;
    float waveX, waveY, waveZ;

    int indX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int indY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int indZ = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if(indX >= rx/2 || indY >= ry || indZ >= rz){
        return;
    }

    igk = 1 + indX + (indY  + indZ * ry)* rx / 2;
    
    lgz = ((indZ + (rz / 2 - 1)) % rz) - (rz / 2 - 1);
    lgy = ((indY + (ry / 2 - 1)) % ry) - (ry / 2 - 1);
    lgx = ((indX + (rx / 2 - 1)) % rx) - (rx / 2 - 1);

    waveX = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLx * lgx;
    waveY = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLy * lgy;
    waveZ = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLz * lgz;
    

    wavevectorX[igk] = waveX;
    wavevectorY[igk] = waveY;
    wavevectorZ[igk] = waveZ;


}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "======================== Start! ========================" << std::endl;
    // int N = 1<<20;
    int rx = 500, ry = 500, rz = 500;
    int N = rx * ry * rz / 2;
    float *wavevectorX;
    float *wavevectorY;
    float *wavevectorZ;

    float boxLength[3];
    boxLength[0] = 3.0;
    boxLength[1] = 3.0;
    boxLength[2] = 3.0;

    // Allocate Unified Memory -- accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&wavevectorX, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&wavevectorY, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&wavevectorZ, N*sizeof(float));

    // Prefetch the data to the GPU
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(wavevectorX, N*sizeof(float), 0);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(wavevectorY, N*sizeof(float), 0);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(wavevectorZ, N*sizeof(float), 0);

    int n_blocksx = 512;
    int n_blocksy = 1;
    int n_blocksz = 1;
    dim3 block(n_blocksx,n_blocksy,n_blocksz);
    dim3 grid((rx + n_blocksx-1) / n_blocksx, (ry + n_blocksy-1) / n_blocksy, (rz + n_blocksz-1) / n_blocksz);

    wavevector<<<grid, block>>>(N, rx, ry, rz, 
                                wavevectorX, wavevectorY, wavevectorZ, 
                                boxLength[0],boxLength[1],boxLength[2]);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    std::cout << "========================= End! =========================" << std::endl;

    int start_p = 1;
    int end_p = 20;
    for(int i = start_p; i <= end_p; i++){
        std::cout << "wavevectorX[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorX[i] << 
        " || wavevectorY[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorY[i] << 
        " || wavevectorZ[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorZ[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(wavevectorX);
    cudaFree(wavevectorY);
    cudaFree(wavevectorZ);

    return 0;
}
```

I am running those calculations on (I have got the MemAvailable by running `cat /proc/meminfo`):

1. Google Colab: with a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz, with MemAvailable: 12281932 kB and a Tesla T4 16Gb;
2. WSL2 on Windows 11: with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10500H CPU @ 2.50GHz, with MemAvailable: 7617120 kB and a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop 6Gb;

Below there is a Table with the time of execution of each code in those systems (I have got these only by adding the `time` command while executing the calculations):

| System / language | Time of execution |
| --- | --- |
| Google Colab / C++ | real 0m1.438s |
| Google Colab / CUDA (still with double precision) | real 0m0.356s |
| WLS2 / C++ | real 0m0.456s |
| WSL2 / CUDA | real about 0m0.8s |

**Edit:** Looking at the times for both C++ calculations and the CUDA carried out on a Tesla T4, we can see that the CUDA version is an improvement (even using double precision in this case and `-O3` flag while compiling the C++ version). The CUDA calculation at the WSL2 is almost the same as the C++ at WSL2.

**1:** Even though I have GPU and CPU with approximated GFLOPS, I would expect to see improvement using the `(512x1x1)` block, and having sets of `(indX, inY, indZ)` being computed in parallel, while comparing to the nested loops in the C++ version.

**2:** If I change `rx`, `ry` and `rz` from 500 to 1000 it works fine on Google Colab, but on WSL2 the C++ run gets killed and the CUDA version returns a segmentation fault while trying to print the results. In this case, the size of data would be `1000*1000*1000*sizeof(double)/2` (which is 3906250 kB). As far as I can see, this should fit in both systems. For the C++ version I read that It's probably killed by kernel's oom killer, but I am not sure about the CUDA version. What I am missing here? (**Edit:** Using blocks as `(512x1x1)` does not lead to segmentation fault on the CUDA code anymore).

I also would appreciate any readings and tips to help me optimize this code :)

**Edit:** I am compiling the C++ version as `g++ -o wavevector_cpp wavevector_cpp.cpp -O3` and the CUDA version as `nvcc -o wavevector_cuda wavevector_cuda.cu -arch=sm_86` (for RTX 3060).

**Edit:** I will run the CUDA calculation running a profiler, so I can provide more information.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256379/discussion-on-question-by-felipe-sc-question-about-gpu-performance-rtx-3060-6gb); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some reading and, according to [this link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations-for-linux-cuda-applications), Unified Memory has limitations on WSL2. Thus, I have carried out a test:

Using the Google Colab environment (which has the T4 GPU) for running two versions of the same code: one that allocates memory manually and another using unified memory, respectively

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "cmath"

// CUDA kernel to calculate wavevectors
__global__ void wavevector(int n, int rx, int ry, int rz, 
                           float *wavevectorX, float *wavevectorY, 
                           float *wavevectorZ, float bLx, float bLy, 
                           float bLz){
    int lgz, lgy, lgx, igk;
    float waveX, waveY, waveZ;

    int indX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int indY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int indZ = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if(indX >= rx/2 || indY >= ry || indZ >= rz){
        return;
    }

    igk = 1 + indX + (indY  + indZ * ry)* rx / 2;
    
    lgz = ((indZ + (rz / 2 - 1)) % rz) - (rz / 2 - 1);
    lgy = ((indY + (ry / 2 - 1)) % ry) - (ry / 2 - 1);
    lgx = ((indX + (rx / 2 - 1)) % rx) - (rx / 2 - 1);

    waveX = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLx * lgx;
    waveY = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLy * lgy;
    waveZ = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLz * lgz;
    

    wavevectorX[igk] = waveX;
    wavevectorY[igk] = waveY;
    wavevectorZ[igk] = waveZ;


}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "======================== Start! ========================" << std::endl;
    int rx = 1000, ry = 1000, rz = 1000;
    int N = rx * ry * rz / 2;
    float *wavevectorX, *h_wavevectorX;
    float *wavevectorY, *h_wavevectorY;
    float *wavevectorZ, *h_wavevectorZ;

    float boxLength[3];
    boxLength[0] = 3.0;
    boxLength[1] = 3.0;
    boxLength[2] = 3.0;

    // Allocate memory manually
    cudaMalloc(&wavevectorX, (N+1)*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&wavevectorY, (N+1)*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&wavevectorZ, (N+1)*sizeof(float));

    h_wavevectorX = (float*)malloc((N+1)*sizeof(float));
    h_wavevectorY = (float*)malloc((N+1)*sizeof(float));
    h_wavevectorZ = (float*)malloc((N+1)*sizeof(float));

    int n_blocksx = 8;
    int n_blocksy = 8;
    int n_blocksz = 8;
    dim3 block(n_blocksx,n_blocksy,n_blocksz);
    dim3 grid((rx + n_blocksx-1) / n_blocksx, (ry + n_blocksy-1) / n_blocksy, (rz + n_blocksz-1) / n_blocksz);

    wavevector<<<grid, block>>>(N, rx, ry, rz, 
                                wavevectorX, wavevectorY, wavevectorZ, 
                                boxLength[0],boxLength[1],boxLength[2]);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    std::cout << "========================= End! =========================" << std::endl;

    // Copying things back to host
    // cudaMemcpy(h_wavevectorX, wavevectorX, (N+1)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // cudaMemcpy(h_wavevectorY, wavevectorY, (N+1)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // cudaMemcpy(h_wavevectorZ, wavevectorZ, (N+1)*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Check results
    // int start_p = 450;
    // int end_p = 500;
    // for(int i = start_p; i <= end_p; i++){
    //     std::cout << "wavevectorX[" << i << "] = " << h_wavevectorX[i] << 
    //     " || wavevectorY[" << i << "] = " << h_wavevectorY[i] << 
    //     " || wavevectorZ[" << i << "] = " << h_wavevectorZ[i] << std::endl;
    // }

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(wavevectorX);
    cudaFree(wavevectorY);
    cudaFree(wavevectorZ);
    free(h_wavevectorX);
    free(h_wavevectorY);
    free(h_wavevectorZ);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
%%cuda --name wavevector_k.cu

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "cmath"

// CUDA kernel to calculate wavevectors
__global__ void wavevector(int n, int rx, int ry, int rz,
                           float *wavevectorX, float *wavevectorY,
                           float *wavevectorZ, float bLx, float bLy,
                           float bLz){
    int lgz, lgy, lgx, igk;
    float waveX, waveY, waveZ;

    int indX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int indY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int indZ = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if(indX >= rx/2 || indY >= ry || indZ >= rz){
        return;
    }

    igk = 1 + indX + (indY  + indZ * ry)* rx / 2;
    
    lgz = ((indZ + (rz / 2 - 1)) % rz) - (rz / 2 - 1);
    lgy = ((indY + (ry / 2 - 1)) % ry) - (ry / 2 - 1);
    lgx = ((indX + (rx / 2 - 1)) % rx) - (rx / 2 - 1);

    waveX = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLx * lgx;
    waveY = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLy * lgy;
    waveZ = float(2.0 * M_PI) / bLz * lgz;


    wavevectorX[igk] = waveX;
    wavevectorY[igk] = waveY;
    wavevectorZ[igk] = waveZ;


}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "======================== Start! ========================" << std::endl;
    int rx = 1000, ry = 1000, rz = 1000;
    int N = rx * ry * rz / 2;
    float *wavevectorX;
    float *wavevectorY;
    float *wavevectorZ;

    float boxLength[3];
    boxLength[0] = 3.0;
    boxLength[1] = 3.0;
    boxLength[2] = 3.0;

    // Allocate Unified Memory -- accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&wavevectorX, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&wavevectorY, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&wavevectorZ, N*sizeof(float));

    // Prefetch the data to the GPU
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(wavevectorX, N*sizeof(float), 0);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(wavevectorY, N*sizeof(float), 0);
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(wavevectorZ, N*sizeof(float), 0);

    int n_blocksx = 8;
    int n_blocksy = 8;
    int n_blocksz = 8;
    dim3 block(n_blocksx,n_blocksy,n_blocksz);
    dim3 grid((rx + n_blocksx-1) / n_blocksx, (ry + n_blocksy-1) / n_blocksy, (rz + n_blocksz-1) / n_blocksz);

    wavevector<<<grid, block>>>(N, rx, ry, rz,
                                wavevectorX, wavevectorY, wavevectorZ,
                                boxLength[0],boxLength[1],boxLength[2]);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    std::cout << "========================= End! =========================" << std::endl;

    // int start_p = 450;
    // int end_p = 500;
    // for(int i = start_p; i <= end_p; i++){
    //     std::cout << "wavevectorX[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorX[i] <<
    //     " || wavevectorY[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorY[i] <<
    //     " || wavevectorZ[" << i << "] = " << wavevectorZ[i] << std::endl;
    // }

    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    // std::cout << " " << std::endl;

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(wavevectorX);
    cudaFree(wavevectorY);
    cudaFree(wavevectorZ);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling them as `nvcc -o /content/src/wavevector_manual_k /content/src/wavevector_manual_k.cu  -arch=sm_75` and `nvcc -o /content/src/wavevector_k /content/src/wavevector_k.cu -arch=sm_75` I have got the following profiles (while running as `time nvprof /content/src/wavevector...`):

```
======================== Start! ========================
==10417== NVPROF is profiling process 10417, command: /content/src/wavevector_manual_k
========================= End! =========================
==10417== Profiling application: /content/src/wavevector_manual_k
==10417== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:  100.00%  69.925ms         1  69.925ms  69.925ms  69.925ms  wavevector(int, int, int, int, float*, float*, float*, float, float, float)
      API calls:   56.16%  101.14ms         3  33.714ms  2.0370ms  96.984ms  cudaMalloc
                   38.84%  69.941ms         1  69.941ms  69.941ms  69.941ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    4.83%  8.6964ms         3  2.8988ms  1.7746ms  3.6260ms  cudaFree
                    0.08%  144.85us       114  1.2700us     155ns  57.517us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.08%  136.54us         1  136.54us  136.54us  136.54us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  12.980us         1  12.980us  12.980us  12.980us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%  6.3260us         1  6.3260us  6.3260us  6.3260us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  4.8700us         1  4.8700us  4.8700us  4.8700us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.00%  2.2090us         3     736ns     254ns  1.6960us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  1.1650us         2     582ns     198ns     967ns  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%     555ns         1     555ns     555ns     555ns  cuModuleGetLoadingMode
                    0.00%     227ns         1     227ns     227ns     227ns  cuDeviceGetUuid

real    0m0.537s
user    0m0.102s
sys 0m0.233s
```

and

```
======================== Start! ========================
==10335== NVPROF is profiling process 10335, command: /content/src/wavevector_k
========================= End! =========================
 
==10335== Profiling application: /content/src/wavevector_k
==10335== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:  100.00%  69.932ms         1  69.932ms  69.932ms  69.932ms  wavevector(int, int, int, int, float*, float*, float*, float, float, float)
      API calls:   42.74%  113.80ms         3  37.934ms  32.751us  113.70ms  cudaMallocManaged
                   26.27%  69.943ms         1  69.943ms  69.943ms  69.943ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                   16.28%  43.359ms         3  14.453ms  13.698ms  15.957ms  cudaFree
                   11.19%  29.802ms         1  29.802ms  29.802ms  29.802ms  cudaLaunchKernel
                    3.45%  9.1945ms         3  3.0648ms  6.7430us  9.0190ms  cudaMemPrefetchAsync
                    0.05%  143.53us       114  1.2590us     160ns  59.795us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.00%  11.416us         1  11.416us  11.416us  11.416us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%  5.9700us         1  5.9700us  5.9700us  5.9700us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  4.7160us         1  4.7160us  4.7160us  4.7160us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.00%  1.4500us         3     483ns     188ns  1.0020us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  1.1310us         2     565ns     208ns     923ns  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%     728ns         1     728ns     728ns     728ns  cuModuleGetLoadingMode
                    0.00%     253ns         1     253ns     253ns     253ns  cuDeviceGetUuid

real    0m0.643s
user    0m0.124s
sys 0m0.302s
```

As we can see: using manual memory allocation or unified memory allocation did not changed the kernel `wavevector` running time and it also did not change significantly the total time of execution.

If I run those codes on WSL2 I get for unified memory a total time of execution of about 5 to 6 seconds, while for manual memory allocation it runs in about 0.622s (which is a time of execution comparable with both runs on Google Colab). Sorry about not having the profiling for WSL2, but - although I read it supports profiling on Windows 11 - I did not managed to get it working so far.

Giving the information on the documentation about unified memory performance on WSL2 and those tests, I can conclude that the weird long total time of execution on WSL2 I was experiencing before is due to its limitations while handling unified memory.

In any case: thanks to everyone in the question comments who gave me all the helpful tips for increasing performance :)